# How to completely remove Mod Pagespeed from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-pagespeed

I have previously installed mod pagespeed on my apache2 but because it doesn't feels like the way I want it.. website ends up slower than I want it to be, I end up remove it using apt-get autoremove.

However, I notice that the following are still being added to the end of each and every of my webpages.

I have restarted apache2 and restarted server and it's still the same. How do I remove it because now that mod page speed is no longer installed, the script below returns 404 error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pagespeed_static/js_defer.tRzI7EHUpg.js">
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable the module:

```
 a2dismod pagespeed
```

2. Restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

3. Remove the package:

```
apt purge mod-pagespeed-stable
```